# Java input not recognizing string

Tags: java

For the following code, if I type y on the keyboard, it enters the else portion of the branch statement. Why is that?

```
    public static void getInput(){
   String response; 
    String[] coins = new String[6]; 

    System.out.println("Would you like to enter your own amount? (y/n)");  

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    response=sc.nextLine();

    if (response=="y"){
       System.out.println("You entered y");
        }
   else{
       System.out.println("You did not enter y, you entered " + response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't have a main class in this program...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want response.equals("y").

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in condition `if(response=="y")`.

**the `equals( )` method compares the characters inside a String object. The `==` operator compares two object references to see whether they refer to the same instance.**

Use

```
(response.equals("y")
```